# Power shell script for copying files with a specific name and a specific extension to a folder from where the script is executing

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

All,

My intention is to copy all the files with starting with the name 'US.Services' and  with the extension .dll from a directory and its sub directories to the place where the script is being executed, i have the following but nothing gets copied. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Get-Childitem -Path ".\.\" -Filter *US.Services*.dll -Recurse | 
    Copy-Item -Destination "."
```

Thanks -Nen

Answer (score 1):

Since PowerShell v3 can use the `$PSScriptRoot` automatic variable to refer to the location where the script is saved (in PowerShell v2 that would be `$here = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path | Split-Path`.

Be aware the both those approaches work only when the script is executed, if you just paste them to PowerShell console they won't return any value.

If I understand your question correctly you look for files that start with the given string and end with the extension, so you need to use the `*` wildcard here: `US.Services*.dll`.

```
Get-Childitem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Recurse -Filter "US.Services*.dll" |
    Copy-Item -Destination $PSScriptRoot
```

This will likely produce exceptions if there are files with the same name copied to the single directory, as two files cannot be named the same within single directory.